# How to capture trend in time-series data for forecasting using scikit-learn's LinearRegression()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, linear-regression

I have read some literature about time series forecasting with ML. I get the concepts of

1. trend
2. seasonality
3. cyclic
4. noise

I would like to use scikit-learn's LinearRegression() as a start to make predictions. If I get it right, I can capture seasonality and cyclic with some feature engineering like `day_of_week`, `month` or `seasons`. I don't get it though, how to capture trend in the data. Is it lag features or a column calculating differences instead of totals?

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer such a broad question.  There is certainly more than one way to try to capture periodic features in times series data.  If you're interested in a more automated solution, I would suggest using the [`prophet`](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/) package.

Comment: I will use `sktime` with `sklearn` models and pass seasonality. BTW: `LinearRegression` is for classification problems

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't LinearRegression for numeric labels and LogisticRegression for classification. I will give sktime and statsmodels definitely a chance, but for this project I would like to stick with scikit. I am trying to get all the basics here.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I am wrong. LinearRegression is for regression problem. You actually use it in place of KNeighborsRegressor or GradientBoostingRegressor in code below.

Answer (score 1):

Linear regression fits the data into a linear model basically a function `Y = W*X` with coefficients `w = (w1, …, wp)` with minimized residual sum of squares between the true values and its corresponding predicted values.

Obviously, time-series data, by nature, is not linear. In order to capture seasonality and cyclic patterns, I would suggest you to use polynomial function, at least with the power of `n > 2`. You can use more advance regression models such as support vector and random forest models.

But for sure, you can start from linear model. Then later, you can easily shift to other advance models after realizing the limitations of linear models.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll do that. I am a bit overwhelmed by packages and names and would like to keep it simple as possible for now. Concerning Feature Engineering, are there any other synthetic features apart from timestamp derived features, differences and lag features?

Answer (score 1):

Check out  `sktime` + `sklearn` to perform forecasting: You would be able to perform most of time-series analysis with them. Example,from my gist, show how you can assemble models two models to predict trends

```py
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sktime.forecasting.base import ForecastingHorizon
from sktime.forecasting.compose import EnsembleForecaster, ReducedForecaster
from sktime.forecasting.model_selection import temporal_train_test_split
from sktime.performance_metrics.forecasting import smape_loss
from sktime.utils.plotting import plot_series


# fetch cyberbullying data from Google trends
pytrend = TrendReq(hl="en-US")
pytrend.build_payload(
    kw_list=[
        "cyberbullying",
    ]
)
cyberbullying_df = pytrend.interest_over_time()

# transfrom DataFrame to Uni-Series of period
fow = cyberbullying_df["cyberbullying"].to_period(freq="W")

y_train, y_test = temporal_train_test_split(fow, test_size=36)
fh = ForecastingHorizon(y_test.index, is_relative=False)

# forecaster ensemble of knn and gradient boosting regressor
forecaster = EnsembleForecaster(
    [
        (
            "knn",
            ReducedForecaster(
                regressor=KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=1),
                window_length=52,
                strategy="recursive",
                scitype="regressor",
            ),
        ),
        (
            "gboost",
            ReducedForecaster(
                regressor=GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=42),
                window_length=52,
                strategy="recursive",
                scitype="regressor",
            ),
        ),
    ]
)

# train an ensemble forecasters and predict|forecast
forecaster.fit(y_train)
y_pred = forecaster.predict(fh)
```

`sktimes` allows you to also use Facebook’s `prophet`. Give it a go as it’s my tool for doing time-series analysis: [sktime](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/sktime)